# Inspect client certificate and more

Tags: iis, url-rewrite-module, arr

I want to use Application request routing and URL rewrite as a reverse proxy. Some of our applications require https and client certificates. Is it possible to write a custom provider of some kind to inspect the incoming request (cookies) plus client certificate and to make a decision whether or not to forward the request?

Regards Robert

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can inspect Cookies with your inbound rule `{HTTP_COOKIE}`:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tconte/archive/2013/09/19/advanced-cookie-based-session-affinity-with-application-request-routing.aspx

And while I have never dealt with Client Certificates, this may help you setup another inspection rule for `X-ARR-ClientCert`:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd443526(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Tanx, but how can I grab the value of X-ARR-ClientCert in a custom IRewriteProvider to e.g. call a service for authorization?